# Inconsitent Python error - Class works fine in terminal, but not in script

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, package, attributeerror

I've run into a strange error I can't quite figure out involving a library installed via pip.

I ran pip3 install mcp9600 to install a library for a temperature sensor, and then verified that this worked as expected by running a python terminal, importing the library, and invoking the relevant class:

[image]

After that I tried to run the exact same thing from a .py file and got the error below:

[image]

I'm really not quite sure what is happening or how to fix it, since I've never had this issue before.  What's going on here?

Comment: Your own file is named `mcp9600.py`. Rename your script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is named `mcp9600.py` so the code  `import mcp9600` imports the script as a module. The script (imported as a module) doesn't have any `MCP9600` hence `AttributeError`.

Rename the script to something else. Even `mcp9600` (without `.py`) is ok. Take the lesson: never name your scripts the same name as Python libraries; for example, never name your scripts `email.py` or `test.py` — they overshadow Python's `email` and `test`.

Comment: Thanks, I literally just figured this out. I come from a C background where things are a little less ambiguous. Lessons learned and thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

your script file is also named `mcp9600.py`, just like the module. Python begins searching for modules in the same directory as the source file, so it finds the script itself instead of the module.

Try renaming your script.

Comment: Thanks, I literally just figured this out too. I didn't know they searched for local libraries first so that makes a lot of sense now!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Seems like I can't call the python script the same as the library name!

I'm new to this but embarrassed all the same!

Comment: no need to be embarrassed, i think anybody who can answer this question ran into it first :)